# Problema de sintaxis con Pascal

Tags: pascal, sintaxis

este es mi primer post y soy nuevo en  esto de la programacion.

La consigna del problema es la siguiente:

Se conoce el saldo inicial de una cuenta bancaria y una serie de movimientos realizados, por cada uno:

- código de movimiento ( D=depósito, R=retiros o F= fin de datos).
- monto

Escribir un programa que ingrese dichos datos y determine el saldo exacto de la cuenta después de procesar las transacciones. Al final del proceso indique cuantas veces no pudo retirar dinero por insuficiencia de fondos.

Este es mi código, al compilarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

> guia3-ejercicio6.pas(30,3) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found**

```
program ejercicio6;


VAR

cod:char;
monto,deposito:word;
nombre:string;

begin

monto := 4000; 


writeln('Hola como te llamas?');
readln(nombre);
writeln('Que operacion desea realizar?');
writeln('Ingrese D si desea hacer un deposito');//Como hago para hacer un salto de linea
writeln('Ingrese R si desea retirar dinero');
readln(cod);

while cod <> 'F' do
  begin
  if cod = 'D' then
      begin 
      writeln('Cuanto dinero desea depositar?');  
      readln(deposito);
      monto := (monto + deposito);
      end;
  else
      if cod = 'R' then
         //begin
         writeln('Cuanto dinero desea retirar?');
         readln(deposito);
         monto := monto - deposito;
         if monto < 0 then
            writeln('Saldo insuficiente intentelo de nuevo');
         end;       
  writeln('Desea realizar otra operacion?. Ingrese F si desea terminar');
  readln(deposito);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta un colocar un end, no cierras el if en `if cod = 'D' then`

```
program ejercicio6;


VAR

cod:char;
monto,deposito:word;
nombre:string;

begin

monto := 4000; 


writeln('Hola como te llamas?');
readln(nombre);
writeln('Que operacion desea realizar?');
writeln('Ingrese D si desea hacer un deposito');//Como hago para hacer un salto de linea
writeln('Ingrese R si desea retirar dinero');
readln(cod);

while cod <> 'F' do
  begin
  if cod = 'D' then
      begin 
      writeln('Cuanto dinero desea depositar?');  
      readln(deposito);
      monto := (monto + deposito);
      end;
  else
      if cod = 'R' then

         writeln('Cuanto dinero desea retirar?');
         readln(deposito);
         monto := monto - deposito;
         if monto < 0 then
            writeln('Saldo insuficiente intentelo de nuevo');
         end;
      end;       
  writeln('Desea realizar otra operacion?. Ingrese F si desea terminar');
  readln(deposito);
  end;


end.
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio